# Laravel specific session link

Tags: laravel, session

We have a page just like the regular food delivery site and we have the following issue:
Normaly we have screen where the user can putin the ZIP Code and then he sees a list of Restaurants according those which are delivering into this delivery area

And then we have page which hasn't a real direct link. This means what ever zip is used the user gets always into for example this page:
test.com/restaurants it doesn't matter which zip he is using.
But we would like to make direct links, for example link for zip 4600, would be:
test.com/restaurants/

But we are not sure how to make this happen since we're using sessions.

SOLVED  VIA SETTING THE ZIP AS SESSION